# Problem with clone project from GitHub in android studio

Tags: android, flutter

what the problem? ,I downloaded a project from GetHub to android studio and when 'Run' the project show me
this lines, I try a lot of different ways but no one of them work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUhsf.png)

can anyone help me please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

respectively can you try this
1-    `gradlew clean`
2-   `gradlew sync`